# Redux: how to define logic between states?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-state

Given the following 2 states as an example:

- `state_a: 'mode_1' | 'mode_2' | 'mode_3'`
- `state_b: boolean`

`state_b` can only be `false` whenever `state_a === 'mode_2'`, and when `state_a !== 'mode_2`', `state_b` should return to the previous value (i.e. it's limits opened up. For example, if it was `true -> false (limited) -> true` or `false -> false (limited) -> false`).

What's the usual practice/style to define such a behavior in Redux?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly you want, from the app's perspective, `state_b` to *always* be false when `state_a === 'mode_2'`, and when `state_a !== 'mode_2'` `state_b` is whatever is stored in state.

On the surface your questions is posed in such a way that it sounds like you want to implement some logic in the reducer functions that coordinates the values between these two states when either of them update. While you *could* do this I suspect a simpler solution is to ***derive*** the provided state when consuming it. In other words, use a selector function to compute derived state, when the `state_a` value is `"mode_2"` then the selector function selecting `state_b` returns false, otherwise it returns the actual `state_b` state value.

Example:

```
import {
  combineReducers,
  configureStore,
  createSlice,
  createSelector
} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { Provider, useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";

const MODES = {
  mode_1: "mode_1",
  mode_2: "mode_2",
  mode_3: "mode_3"
};

const state = createSlice({
  initialState: {
    state_a: MODES.mode_1,
    state_b: true
  },
  name: "state",
  reducers: {
    setMode: (state, action) => {
      state.state_a = action.payload;
    },
    toggleB: (state, action) => {
      state.state_b = !state.state_b;
    }
  }
});

const { setMode, toggleB } = state.actions;

const selectState = (state) => state.state;

const select_a = createSelector([selectState], (state) => state.state_a);
const select_b = createSelector([select_a, selectState], (state_a, state) =>
  state_a !== MODES.mode_2 ? state.state_b : false
);
```

Selecting the state in a component:

```
const state_a = useSelector(select_a);
const state_b = useSelector(select_b);
```

Demo:

[image: Edit redux-how-to-define-logic-between-states]

Comment: Ok, that's one solution, thanks. I came from a project that uses a "settings engine" where each setting will have an observer-pattern hook to "adjust/correct" its own state. The GUI then can do things like `settingA.getValue()` or `settingA.isDisabled()`.  Was hoping for something similar in redux.

Comment: @Ryuu One of the foundations of Redux is that *technically* speaking every reducer function *sees* every dispatched action and is conditionally acting on only those it's interested in. You could add cases to handle the dispatched actions updating other parts of the state tree, but this IMHO unnecessarily couples state branches a bit and introduces additional state to retain the "previous" B state boolean value so it can be restored. I don't recommend it, but if interested I could provide an additional solution doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [Sharing data between slice reducers](https://redux.js.org/usage/structuring-reducers/beyond-combinereducers#sharing-data-between-slice-reducers),

```
import { combineReducers, createStore } from "redux";

type StateA = 'mode_1' | 'mode_2' | 'mode_3';
const stateAReducer = (state: StateA = 'mode_1', action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SWITCH_MODE':
      return action.payload;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

type StateB = boolean;
const stateBReducer = (state: StateB = true, action) => {
  return state;
}

const combinedReducer = combineReducers({
  stateA: stateAReducer,
  stateB: stateBReducer
});

type CrossSliceState = ReturnType<typeof combinedReducer>;
const crossSliceReducer = (state: CrossSliceState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SWITCH_MODE':
      const nextStateA = stateAReducer(state.stateA, action);
      return {
        stateA: nextStateA,
        stateB: nextStateA === 'mode_2' ? false : state.stateB
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

const rootReducer = (state, action) => {
  const intermediateState = combinedReducer(state, action);
  const finalState = crossSliceReducer(intermediateState, action);
  return finalState
}

const store = createStore(rootReducer);
store.subscribe(() => {
  console.log(store.getState());
})
store.dispatch({ type: 'SWITCH_MODE', payload: 'mode_1' });
store.dispatch({ type: 'SWITCH_MODE', payload: 'mode_2' });
store.dispatch({ type: 'SWITCH_MODE', payload: 'mode_1' });
```

Output:

```bash
{ stateA: 'mode_1', stateB: true }
{ stateA: 'mode_2', stateB: false }
{ stateA: 'mode_1', stateB: false }
```